# How to use multiple values in a single np.where condition?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, series

I have a dataframe like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'text': ["Hi how","I am fine","Ila say Hi","hello"],
                   'tokens':["test","correct","Tim",np.nan],
                   'labels':['A','B','C','D']})
```

Instead of multiple np.where conditions, I would like to use `Or` or `|` operator to check for multiple values in `np.where` condition like below

```
df['labels'] = np.where(df['tokens'] == ('test'|'correct'|is.na()),'new_label',df['labels'])
```

However, this results in an error

> TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'

I expect my output to be like as shown below. How can I do this efficiently for big data with million of records?

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First idea is replace missing values by some value from list, e.g. `test` and then compare by [`Series.isin`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.isin.html):

```
df['labels'] = np.where(df['tokens'].fillna('test').isin(['test','correct']),
                        'new_label',
                        df['labels'])
print (df)
         text   tokens     labels
0      Hi how     test  new_label
1   I am fine  correct  new_label
2  Ila say Hi      Tim          C
3       hello      NaN  new_label
```

Or chain another mask by `|` for bitwise `OR` form compare `NaN`s:

```
df['labels'] = np.where(df['tokens'].isin(['test','correct']) | df['tokens'].isna(),
                        'new_label',
                        df['labels'])
print (df)
         text   tokens     labels
0      Hi how     test  new_label
1   I am fine  correct  new_label
2  Ila say Hi      Tim          C
3       hello      NaN  new_label
```

Comment: wow, first approach of fillin na with some dummy value and reduce code length is good..